# HABTM models and dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

There are three things involved in the application that I'm developing: Reports, Sections, and Writers.

A Report has_many Sections and Writers. Sections and Writers have a HABTM relationship with each other, since a writer can choose to write several sections, and a section can be written by many articles.

The way I have it displayed is this:

- Report

  - Section 1

    - Writer 1
    - Writer 2
  - Section 2

    - Writer 1
    - Writer 3
  - Section 3

    - Writer 4
    - Writer 2

I can do that easily enough in the index. My problem is with the form in `view/writers/_form.html.erb`.

When a writer is created, I want to assign the writer to 1.) a project, and 2.) a section.

I actually have it working for the most part using check boxes.

```
<%= f.label :report_id %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :report_id, Report.all, :id, :name %>

<%= f.label "Section" %><br />
<% Section.order(:name).all.each do |section| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "writer[section_ids][]", section.id, @writer.section_ids.include?(section.id) %>
    <%= section.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

But this gives me problems. This way, ALL the sections from ALL reports are displayed. I don't want this. So I changed it to:

```
<% Section.order(:name).where(report_id:@writer.report_id).each do |section| %>
```

But this way, no section checkboxes appear when a new writer is being created. It only appears in the edit page, after the writer has been saved with a report assigned to them already.

It makes sense why it does this, but is there any way I can make it so that reports are "assigned" once they're selected, so the proper section?

I'm trying to follow Ryan Bates' Railcast at http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised but he works with two collection_select fields, and the model associations aren't exactly the same with each other..

Answer (score 0):

So you'd like the checkboxes to change as the user changes the Report? This is something you will have to do with javascript. The server side cannot make this happen.

You can however take a different approach and assign the writer in two steps. First assign the report. Then, since you've set the report_id, the next step can generate the correct checkboxes for that report and you can set the sections.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know nearly enough Javascript to do it all in one step. I ended up just displaying the form partial on the Show page as well (which the users are redirected to after the create action) so they can tick off the checkboxes.. Not quite what I like, but good enough for now.